# search and substitute texts in a list in python

Tags: python, replace, substitution

I do have a list data for text mining analysis and below is a simple example

```
 list=[['memuniyet', 'basarıl', 'memnunm'],['konuda', 'memnunuz', 'basarılı']]
```

My goal is the search and scan within the list and replace words if there is a word like '%mem%'  and replace it with 'memnun' and like '%bas%' then replace it with 'basarılı'. So the final outcome will look like

```
new_list=[['memnun', 'basarılı', 'memnun'],['konuda', 'memnun', 'basarılı']]
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you.

```
list=[['memuniyet', 'basarıl', 'memnunm'],['konuda', 'memnunuz', 'basarılı']]

n_list =[['memnun' if 'mem' in element else 'basarılı' if 'bar' in element else element for element in sub] for sub in list]
```

This returns,

```
[['memnun', 'basarıl', 'memnun'], ['konuda', 'memnun', 'basarılı']]
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to replace each word one by one

Comment: would you please explain briefly?

Comment: like using re.sub(r"mem", "memnun", list)

Comment: would you want something like this? 
`n_l=[func(i,'mem','memnun') for i in list]`